# Is this function pos. semidefinite?

Tags: real-analysis

We have $f:\mathbb{Z}^2\mapsto\mathbb{R}$ with
\begin{align}
f(i,j):=C\cdot |j-i|^d
\end{align}
with $d\in(-1,0)$ and $C>0$.
Is f positive semidefinite? By that we mean, that
\begin{align}
\sum_{i,j=1}^k a_i a_j f(i,j) \geq 0
\end{align}
for all $a:=(a_1,...,a_k)'\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $k\in\mathbb{N}$, with $a\neq(0,...,0)$.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: If your definition of "positive semidefinite" is "never negative, but can be zero" then, yes, that function is positive semidefinite.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That wasn't what I meant. I updated my question for a hopefully better understanding.

Comment: How is $f(i,i)$ defined?

Comment: Do you know any function that is positive semidefinite by that definition?